# Convert into wrong time while converting UTC time to current time zone time

Tags: ios, swift, timezone, datetime-format

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = inputFormate //HH:mm:ss
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")

let dt = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
// Setting daylightSavingTimeOffset still getting wrong output
//let offset = dateFormatter.timeZone.daylightSavingTimeOffset(for: dt!)
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
dateFormatter.dateFormat = outputFormate //hh:mma
dateFormatter.amSymbol = "am"
dateFormatter.pmSymbol = "pm"
//return dateFormatter.string(from: (dt ?? Date()) + offset)
return dateFormatter.string(from: dt ?? Date())
```

This working correct for IST but giving me wrong output for AEST(Sydney Australia).

> Input: 17:00:00 (UTC)
>   Output: 04:00am (AEST) and it should be 03:00am

Comment: maybe you should add daylightSaving?

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik by adding daylightSaving still getting same output.

Comment: What do you get for `print(TImeZone.current)`? Sydney is currently in UTC+10 so yes, you should get `03:00am` from `17:00:00 UTC`. My own test of your code, setting the date formatter's timezone to UTC+10, does give 3am as expected. So I suspect your current timezone isn't set to what you think it is.

Comment: @rmaddy The time zone is 
Australia/Sydney (current)
  - identifier : "Australia/Sydney"
  - kind : "current"
  ▿ abbreviation : Optional<String>
    - some : "GMT+10"
  - secondsFromGMT : 36000
  - isDaylightSavingTime : false

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you have comes from missing the specific year, month and day.

Because currently, it is calculating at it is 2000-01-01 and this is a problem for the daylightSaving.

I execute your code and it doesn't give me the right time.

I change just these two lines and everything was fine

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let dt = dateFormatter.date(from: "2019-08-01 10:00:00")
```

In general, your code is fine but you need to check the date for the correct offset between timezones.

Comment: I have only time :(

Comment: I don't know what is the case but you should relate it with something for example with today or with 2000-01-01 and than your  code will be fine.